# regex replace only words with words from replacement file

Tags: regex, sed

I've found a way to replace words in a file `inputfile.txt` with matching words from `substitutes.txt` in bash with `sed`.

For example:
File `substitutes.txt` contains word pairs to be replaced:
`Good=ok`
`sat=cat`

I use the following code:

```
sed -e 's/^/s%/' -e 's/=/%/' -e 's/$/%g/' substitutes.txt |
sed -f - inputfile.txt >outputfile.txt
```

This replacement ist a bit aggressive and replaces `Goodyear` with `okyear` or `saturday` with `caturday`, but it should leave those words alone.

**Here's the question**:
How can word boundaries (`\b`) be implemented into this replacement, so that only words (and not parts of words) will be replaced?

Comment: `sed -e 's/^/s%\\b/' -e 's/=/\\b%/' -e 's/$/%g/' substitutes.txt`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your search and replace list only contains letter words, just enclosing the LHS with `\b` word boundaries should work:

```
sed -e 's/^/s%\\b/' -e 's/=/\\b%/' -e 's/$/%g/' substitutes.txt
#             ^^^           ^^^
```

The list of regex commands will then look like

```
root@ip-172-30-0-77:/home/ubuntu# sed -e 's/^/s%\\b/' -e 's/=/\\b%/' -e 's/$/%g/' substitutes.txt
s%\bGood\b%ok%g
s%\bsat\b%cat%g
```

Note you may add more preprocessing in case the terms may contain special chars, see [Is it possible to escape regex metacharacters reliably with sed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29613304). Then, you will have to also reconsider `=` as a delimiter between the search-replacement pair (a mulitcharacter  separator is a better bet).

Comment: In fact the replacements only contain letter words, so your example works pretty well. Thanks for the good hint about escaping!

Comment: @Kabauter Glad it does, I had to add that bit since dynamic regex creation is fraught with potential bottlenecks.